# Startup Cube not showing up

Tags: mesh

I reset my computer, downloaded blender, uninstalled and reinstalled and tried restoring the program to it's factory settings but nothing has worked. My object mode doesn't work properly while everything else does. If I switch to Edit, I can see it fine, but in Object mode it's gone. Meshes are ever worse. I try to add a circle and it's just random lines coming from it's center point. Can someone please help me? Rigging in grease pencil is so hard because of this problem.[image: circle mesh]

[image: cube]

Comment: I have seen many others have the same issues. This could be a bug. Try making sure your graphics card drivers are up to date, as the viewport workbench render engine uses it.